# Как заполнять данными столбец таблицы если у нее есть внешний ключ?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Только начал изучать базы даных. Есть следующие таблицы.

```
CREATE TABLE [Language]
(
 [language_id] INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL, 
 [name]        NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Languages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([language_id] ASC)
);
GO

-- ************************************** [Level]

CREATE TABLE [Level]
(
 [level_id] INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
 [name]     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Levels] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([level_id] ASC)
);
GO

-- ************************************** [Teacher]

CREATE TABLE [Teacher]
(
 [teacher_id] INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
 [first_name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 [last_name]  NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 [e-mail]     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 [mobile_number]     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Teacher] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([teacher_id] ASC)
);
GO

-- ************************************** [Group]

CREATE TABLE [Group]
(
 [group_id]    INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
 [start_date]  SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL ,
 [end_date]    SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL ,
 [level_id]    INT NOT NULL ,
 [teacher_id]  INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 [language_id] INT NOT NULL ,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Courses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([group_id] ASC),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_49] FOREIGN KEY ([level_id])
  REFERENCES [Level]([level_id]),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_52] FOREIGN KEY ([teacher_id])
  REFERENCES [Teacher]([teacher_id]),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_55] FOREIGN KEY ([language_id])
  REFERENCES [Language]([language_id])
);
GO

-- ************************************** [Student]

CREATE TABLE [Student]
(
 [student_id] INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
 [first_name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 [last_name]  NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 [e-mail]     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 [number]     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 [group_id]   INT NOT NULL ,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([student_id] ASC),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_59] FOREIGN KEY ([group_id])
  REFERENCES [Group]([group_id])
);
GO
```

Как заполнить данными столбцы без внешних ключей я знаю(например ниже наведен код для заполнения данными таблицу `Level`), а как нужно заполнить столбцы у которых есть внешние ключи? Так же как и обычные столбцы?

```
INSERT INTO [Level] (name) VALUES 
('Beginner'),
('Elementary'),
('Pre-Intermediate'),
('Intermediate'),
('Upper-Intermediate'),
('Advanced'),
('Proficient')
```

Comment: Точно такой как и обычные записи, только запись на которую вы ссылаетесь ключем должна быть в бд на момент вставки дочерней записи.

Comment: Понял, спасибо) а можно как-то заполнять так чтобы чтобы прямо вставлять с одной таблицы в другую?

Comment: Можно, но зависит от того какой именно SQL у вас, в MySQL это выглядит как `Insert into table select from table2`,  этот запрос скопирует содержимое `table2` в `table`

Comment: я использую ms sql server